# How to introduce sin as a function on real line to school students

Tags: trigonometry

Question is as in the title :

How to introduce $\sin$ as a function on real line.

All they know about $\sin, \cos$ is that they eat angles and gives numbers, not any angle but angles like $0°,30°,45°,60°, 90°$. They also know some formulas, for example about $\sin(A+B),\sin(A-B)$.

Using this, they know what is $\sin(15°), \cos(15°)$ and something similar.

Just knowing this, what are some of the ways to introduce $\sin$ as a function on whole real line?

Nothing is special about $\sin$. If you think it is easy to introduce $\cos$, please proceed to give some ideas about introducing $\cos$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x>0$ be a real number. To define $\cos(x)$ or $\sin(x)$, imagine that the segment $[0;x]$ is a rope. Starting at the point of coordinate (1;0), wrap that rope anticlockwise around the trigonometric circle to see the point where $x$ lands. Then project that point on the axes to get $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$. If $x < 0$, do the same but clockwise.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this kind of argument. BTW, I am also interested in giving them the formula for $\sin$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik The best formula you can get for $\sin$ is a Taylor expansion, that sounds way beyhond school students.

The "wraping" of the real line can be found in more or less every french school book that covers trigonometry.

Comment: Can you name one french school book in trigonometry that is written in English? :D

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik I'm sorry, I can't. ;D

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your answer. +1